# How to restrict UISearchController from hiding view Navigation Bar in IOS8

Tags: ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a UIViewController embedded in a popover. This controller has two subviews, a `UINavigationBar` and a `MapView`. I try to implement the new search Controller i.e. `UISearchController` as UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS8.

When I click in the search bar (displaying two scopes), everything is all right, and the navigation bar is still visible. But when I start typing in the search bar, the navigation bar and the keyboard disappear, replaced by a dim map view. I tried to add `self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;` in the `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` method as well as `searchBarShoulBeginEditing:` method, but got no result. (note that the controller `viewDidLoad` defines `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`)

Any idea to force navigation being displayed anytime?

Comment: Can you post your code (at least the parts of code which are relevant to `UISearchController`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set this property `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` in ViewDidLoad. Then implement `searchBarTextShouldBeginEditing` and `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` methods as such:

```
-(void)searchBarTextShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
[searchControllerMain setActive:YES];
[searchControllerMain.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];}
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
[searchControllerMain setActive:YES];
[searchControllerMain.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
searchControllerMain.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
}
```

It will work!!

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have a tab controller inside a nav controller though.